# Python multiprocess pool processes count

Tags: python, process, pool, multiprocess

I am using a linux server with 128 cores, but I'm not the only one using it so I want to make sure that I use a maximum of 60 cores for my program. The program I'm writing is a series of simulations, where each simulation is parallelized itself. The number of cores of such a single simulation can be chosen, and I typically use 12.

So in theory, I can run 5 of these simulations at the same time, which would result in (5x12) 60 cores used in total. I want start the simulations from python (since that's where all the preprocessing happens), and my eye has caught the multiprocessing library, especially the Pool class.

Now my question is: should I use 
    pool = Pool(processes=5)
or
    pool = Pool(processes=60)

The idea being: does the processes argument signify the amount of workers used (where each worker is assigned 12 cores), or the total amount of processes available?

Comment: _processes_ is the number of worker processes to use. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool)

Comment: I believe it the total number of processes available in the Pool that will be allocated from the number of physical cores the system has available—so you probably want `Pool(processes=60)`.

Answer (score 1):

The argument 'processes' in Pool means the total subprocess you want to create in this program. So If you want to use all 60 cores, here should be 60.